# Issue porting to Mono: Failed to convert parameters due to namespace issue during deserialization

Tags: c#, wcf, ubuntu, mono, deserialization

On Windows, with .NET. There is no issue serializing or deserializing the following WCF web object:

```
[DataContract]
public class Payload
{
    public Payload() {}

    public class SubPayloadOne
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubPayloadTwo
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public SubPayloadOne P1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public SubPayloadTwo P2 { get; set; }
}
```

On Mono (on Ubuntu), attempting to deserialize the web object in the example above will result in the following error: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to set value of type String[Payload+SubPayloadOne+Name] for property String[Payload+SubPayloadTwo+Name] String ---> System.ArgumentException: failed to convert parameters

My theory is that Mono is not including the full namespace when deserializing the object. In other words, it is confusing Payload.SubPayloadTwo.Name for Payload.SubPayloadOne.Name, because both objects are "Name" if you do not consider their full namespace.

Following through on the theory above, I tried resolving this problem by renaming Payload.SubPayloadOne.Name or Payload.SubPayloadTwo.Name to something else, for example, Payload.SubPayloadTwo.NameTwo. Which did work. However, this would break reverse compatibility with existing product (since existing Payload objects are already in databases).

If at all possible, I'm looking for a solution that does not involve changing the web object. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a Mono bug to me, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Do you not need DataMember attributes on the fields?

Comment: Thanks Pete. I forgot those in the example, though they do exist in the actual implementation. Doesn't affect the bug though :) I updated the example.